# Service started but not shown in setting -> running services

Tags: android, service

I have a android service extends from Service and onStartCommand is return START_STICKY.  The service is self running service and no one bind on it.

In my MainActivity, I am using

```
Intent startService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
startService(startService);
```

Everything is working fine except in Setting -> Running Service 'show cached process' tab not shown anything for my application but in 'cached background process' tab show "Cached services in use".   I doubt that why no shown in 'show cached process' tab but I see other app has shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that your service is running on the same process as the application. If you set  `android:process=":yourServiceName"` in the manifest file, your service will start a new process and you can see your service.

Also, do check if your service is actually running using this method

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```